# Opening modalpopextender inside a user control in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two user controls in my web application. Both user controls have modalpopupextender.
When i am adding scriptmanager to both the user controls it gives a error that :

```
Only one instance of a scriptmanager can be added to the page
```

Hence i provided scriptmanager for only one user control. Here the popup works fine.
But in other usercontrol as i am not adding scriptmanager popup does not work.
How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `scriptmanager` on master page or your container page.